# Is it beneficial to use OOP on large datasets in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, oop, data-driven

I'm implementing Kalman Filter on two types of measurements. I have GPS measurement every second (1Hz) and 100 measurment of accelration in one second (100Hz).
So basically I have two huge tables and they have to be fused at some point. My aim is: I really want to write readable and maintainable code.

My first approach was: there is a class for both of the datatables (so an object is a datatable), and I do bulk calculations in the class methods (so almost all of my methods include a for loop), until I get to the actual filter. I found this approach a bit too stiff. It works, but there is so much data-type transformation, and it is just not that convenient.

Now I want to change my code. If I would want to stick to OOP, my second try would be: every single measurment is an object of either the GPS_measurment or the acceleration_measurement. This approach seems better, but this way thousands of objects would have been created.

My third try would be a data-driven design, but I'm not really familiar with this approach.

Which paradigm should I use? Or perhaps it should be solved by some kind of mixture of the above paradigms? Or should I just use procedural programming with the use of pandas dataframes?

Comment: `numpy` arrays contain objects (such as your custom class) lose most of the fast computational advantages of `numpy`.  The fast numeric code is compiled to use floats and integers.  And since `pandas` use arrays, that same goes for that.  `pandas` readily switches Series to object dtype if they contain strings or objects like `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would want to use `pandas`. OOP is a concept btw, not something you explicitly code in inflexibly. Generally speaking, you only want to define your own classes if you plan on extending them or encapsulating certain features. `pandas` and `numpy` are 2 modules that already do almost everything you can ask for with regards to data and they are faster in execution.